# How do we handle duplicate questions from a pending merged site (Guitars)?

Tags: discussion

This may be a moot point because the Guitars.SE merge could be happening really soon but I have seen a couple of duplicate questions that we already answered over on guitars on Music.SE already. Is it acceptable to simply redirect the user to the already answered question? How do we handle this scenario?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Guitars site won't exist in the future.

Comment: The assumption was that after the merge happens those questions will be migrated over, and one of them closed as a duplicate. So, the redirection would be temporary.

Comment: As has been stated, not all questions will be migrated over.

Comment: In that case, I'll likely migrate my answers to any duplicates that come around. Thanks!

Comment: Migration will happen [in a week or two](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/60/when-will-this-site-be-merged-with-the-other-music-proposals/62#62).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not redirect a user who asks an on-topic question to go to a different site.  Remember that it's OK to duplicate content; if it's an exact duplicate, then one will simply be closed and point to the other when the sites are merged.  The answers can even be moved from one question to the other if the mods think it is warranted.

As for answering the question, I would go ahead.  If the answer from Guitars is good, copy it and reference it.  Make your answer Community Wiki if you don't feel comfortable receiving rep for "stealing" an answer.

Comment: Indeed, just let the migration occur naturally and don't care about too specific non-issues. :)

Answer (score -1):

Moderators have the ability to merge questions.  I think those questions should be flagged here in meta after the merge occurs, and the mods can take appropriate action on a question-by-question basis.